# Use load static in django templates gets messy code

Tags: django, templates

In my template, i use load static to load static files:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/default.min.css?t=227' %}" />
```

but in the browser html changed to this  messy code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/default.min.css%3Ft%3D227">
```

Comment: Are you asking about the /static/css thing or the % symbols introduced in the path of your css file?

Comment: I mean in the browser html, it is messy code, I can not import the css correctly.

Comment: Do you have a default.min.css inside your /static/css/ ? If yes then probably you can try changing the name default.min.css?t=227 to default.min.css .

Comment: yes I have defalt.min.css. @ShivamSharma I did that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the query args outside the template tag.

```
"{% static 'css/default.min.css' %}?t=227"
```